# NSDates and TimeIntervals

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I'm struggling to understand how to use NSDates properly.

I have an event that instantiates a `timingDate = [NSDate date];`

I then later on what to record the time intervals betweeen user's touches.
So I want to find the interval between the timingDate and the user touch in milliseconds.
Then I want to reset the timingDate to be equal to the touchTime so that the next time the screen is touched I can find the differnce between the previous touch and the present touch. I hope that makes sense.  But I am going around in circles because I don't understand how to use NSDates or NSIntervals.  The properties interval touchTime and timingDate are all currently NSDate types - Is this right?

So I've tried a lot of different things like

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    touchTime = timingDate;
    interval  = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timingDate]; // should be the time difference from when the timingDate was first set and when the user touched the screen.
    touchTime = [[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:timingDate]doubleValue];
    timingDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:touchTime];
    NSLog(@"Time taken Later: %f", [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceDate:timingDate]);
  }
```

Comment: `timeIntervalSinceDate` returns an `NSInterval`, which is not a object type but a simple numeric type.  It's really an alias for `double`, so to convert from `NSInterval` to `double` you can simply cast with `(double)` (not `doubleValue`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit complex! You just need to calculate the difference between `timingDate` and the time that the touch occurred, and then set `timingDate` to the current time so that you can perform this calculation on every touch event.

To find the difference between `timingDate` and the first touch, you can use NSDate's `timeIntervalSinceDate` with the current time. This will return an NSTimeInterval value, which represents a time value in seconds with sub-millisecond precision. Here's an example:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:timingDate];
NSLog(@"Time taken: %f seconds / %f milliseconds",timeInterval,timeInterval*1000);
```

Then, in order to set your timingDate to the current time, simply use `timingDate = currentDate;`. This will allow you to continuously measure the time difference between touches.

Comment: Of course - I don't know why I didn't just reset timingDate like you suggest.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) Don't call `[NSDate date]` twice. You end up with two different dates and things don't quite add up over time. 2) Instead of using `[NSDate date]`. get the timestamp from the actual event. `NSTimeInterval touchTimestamp = [[touches anyObject] timestamp];`

Comment: @rmaddy Good points, I've edited the code so that [NSDate date] is only called once. Re: UITouch timestamp, this could be used to calculate the time difference between touches however I believe on the first touch, the OP needed to calculate the difference from an NSDate date that was set elsewhere.

Comment: My point is that `[NSDate date]` gives you the timestamp of when the code is run while getting the touch's timestamp is from when the user actually touched the screen. Of course the difference between the two will be tiny.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I understand that but OP stated that the first `timingDate` value did not come from a touch event but was instantiated at some other point in time as an NSDate object. `[NSDate date]` cannot be compared to a `[UITouch timestamp]` in any simple way, correct?

Comment: Why not? Getting the `NSTimerInterval` from an `NSDate` is trivial.

Comment: You need two `NSDate` objects in order to get an `NSTimeInterval`, like for example, the sample code that I posted in my answer. If you start with one `NSDate` object, how do you compare that with a `[UITouch timestamp]` value? The date object represents a point in time, and the time interval is the number of seconds since another point in time that is completely unrelated to the date object.

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimeInterval` is a double which represents seconds.

`NSDate` is an object that holds the date/time.

Here is an example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate * lastTouchDate;

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastTouch = 0;

    if(self.lastTouchDate){

        secondsSinceLastTouch = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.lastTouchDate];

        NSLog(@"It's been %.1f seconds since the user touched the screen", secondsSinceLastTouch);

    }else{

        NSLog(@"This is the first time the user touched the screen");

    }

    self.lastTouchDate = [NSDate date];

}
```

If you don't want the interval between the last time you touched it, do not update the self.lastTouchDate after initialization and it will be seconds since the date was initialized.

Answer (score 1):

So, the first thing that you need to understand is that `-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]` returns an `NSTimeInterval`, which is really just a double value.

In your example above, you haven't declared your variables with types, but if you look at the value your variable `interval` it should be a decimal value of seconds since the time represented by `timingDate`.

---

Assuming that `timingDate` is an `NSDate` object, and it is set before this code is run, this code should print the time (seconds) to the debug console.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timingDate];
NSLog(@"Time between touches %f", interval);
```

---

Here is the NSDate class documentation, in case you were having trouble finding it.
( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate )

Comment: Actually, that's the NSTimeInterval documentation.  NSDate is at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDate

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks so much Hot Licks. I will correct the link above.